# Vala networking packets in DataInputStream

Tags: networking, packet, vala, gio

I've been playing around with networking in Vala but I can't find any documentation on how to read a signal packet or tell when one packet ends and another one starts in the incoming data stream.

Here is my code so far:

```
bool on_incoming_connection (SocketService socket, SocketConnection conn, Object? unuesd) {
    stdout.printf ("Got incoming connection\n");
    // Process the request asynchronously
    process_request.begin (conn, socket);
    return true;
}

async void process_request (SocketConnection conn, SocketService socket) {
    try {
        var dis = new DataInputStream (conn.input_stream);
        var dos = new DataOutputStream (conn.output_stream);

        uint8 byte = 0;

        do {
            byte = dis.read_byte();
            stdout.printf ("Got: %d\n", byte);
        } while (byte != 0);


        // The connection is automatically closed because conn is destroyed upon function return.
    } catch (Error e) {
        stderr.printf ("%s\n", e.message);
    }
}

void main () {
    MainLoop loop = new MainLoop ();
    
    var service = new SocketService ();

    Cancellable cancellable = new Cancellable ();
    cancellable.cancelled.connect (() => {
        service.stop ();
        loop.quit ();
    });

    try {
        service.add_inet_port (33333, null);
    } catch (Error e) {
        stderr.printf ("%s\n", e.message);
    }
    
    service.incoming.connect (on_incoming_connection);
    service.start ();
    loop.run ();
}
```

Comment: You can't. It's a stream. If you want message boundaries you have to implement them yourself at both ends.

Comment: Does GIO/GLib provide any networking APIs that allow per packet boundaries then? If not, are there any Vala libraries that provide this feature?

Comment: It is the *protocol* that has the feature. Protocols have either fixed-length records, record terminators (e.g. newlines), records with length word-prefixes, or are self-describing some other way, like XML or ASN.1.

Comment: In this case, I do not have control over the client and the packets do not have special separating characters like newlines. So I need to have some way of distinguishing individual packets there is no way of doing it with a stream. and I know that. I am just asking if there is any Vala library that does do this because I can't find anything like this in GIO.

Comment: If that is really the case, which I doubt, you have been set an impossible problem. But I'm practically certain you will find that your given client-server protocol behaves as I have described, so all you have to do is implement it correctly.